# How to save video in android HTC from server?

Tags: android, video

I am getting a url from server & i want to save video in my android htc device .
I am getting Some errors:-----
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/543b8417-6e67-4755-8c68-b93373f9d9e2.wmv (Permission denied)
& address family not supported.
I have given all permission in menifest file.
My code is :-
videoUrl = "http://125.63.71.222/fliptest/uservideo/543b8417-6e67-4755-8c68-b93373f9d9e2.wmv";

```
    String LocalFilePath = videoUrl.substring(
            videoUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, videoUrl.length());
    File dire = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), LocalFilePath);






        int bytesread = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
        InputStream strm = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        String LocalFile = null;
        FileOutputStream foStream;
        BufferedOutputStream writer = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            videoUrl = videoUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(videoUrl);

            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            entity = response.getEntity();
            strm = entity.getContent();







            LocalFile = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + LocalFilePath;
            //directory = null;
            foStream = new FileOutputStream(dire);
            writer = new BufferedOutputStream(foStream);
            do {
                bytesread = strm.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                if (bytesread > 0) {
                    writer.write(bytes, 0, bytesread);
                    writer.flush();
                }
            } while (bytesread > 0);

            writer.close();
            foStream.close();

            strm.close();
            return;

        } catch (Exception e) {
        //  dire.delete();              
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: Where do you want to save it?? Write the path

Comment: I want to save it in my android device gallary. But what is the right path I am not getting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would slightly modify your code:

```
String videoUrl = "http://125.63.71.222/fliptest/uservideo/543b8417-6e67-4755-8c68-b93373f9d9e2.wmv";
String LocalFilePath = videoUrl.substring(videoUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, videoUrl.length());
File dire = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), LocalFilePath);

int bytesread = -1; // i would change it to -1
byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
InputStream strm = null;
FileOutputStream foStream;

try {
    videoUrl = videoUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
    URL url = new URL(videoUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    strm = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    foStream = new FileOutputStream(dire);

    //typical pattern for reading
    while ((bytesread = strm.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        foStream.write(bytes, 0, bytesread);
    }

    foStream.flush();
    foStream.close();
    strm.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

You need two permissions to run this code - you've already mentioned you have them but quick reminder:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And don't forget to run this task asynchronously.

Best Regards

Comment: I am still getting an error:-java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/dcim/

Comment: I have given different path such as mnt/sdcard,system/data

Comment: I tested this code my HTC Sensation (with Android 4.0.3) and worked fine - I downloaded your video successfully. Which version of android do you have? Which HTC? Do you have enough space on sdcard? Can you access your sdcard outside of your appliaction using any file viewer? Could you also post full stacktrace? Also check code [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in section "Checking media availability" and post results.

Comment: Thanks, Its working after changing mode in "Change Only" from "Disk Mode"